# How should I build a React app to run from a subdirectory on my domain called cms?

Tags: reactjs

i want my application to run from a subdirectory i.e. https://domainname.co.ug/cms/

Comment: If you're using CRA did you read https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths? If not we'd need a [mre] of your configuration.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In the package.json file add `homepage` key at very top and its value should be the domains on which you want it to be served.

`"homepage":"your domain/sub-domain"`